# Conditional select queries with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

i had some php scripts working with mysql_query but now i was trying to change it to PDO (to be less vulnerable and more secure they say) but i'm having some problems with conditional select queries. 
I have the following code:

```
$querydatahora = $conn->prepare('SELECT 
    Linhas.NomeLinha, Maquinas.Nome as maquina, Tecnicos.Nome, Avarias.DataHoraInicioAvaria, 
    Avarias.DataHoraFimAvaria, Avarias.Descricao, Avarias.Solucao, Avarias.TipoSolucao 
    FROM Avarias, Tecnicos, Linhas, Maquinas, avariatecnico 
    where Linhas.IDLinha = Avarias.IDLinha and avariatecnico.IDAvaria = avarias.IDAvaria and Avariatecnico.IDTecnico = Tecnicos.IDTecnico and 
    Maquinas.IDMaquina = Avarias.IDMaquina and DataHoraInicioAvaria >= :datetimepicker AND DataHoraFimAvaria <= :datetimepicker1 ');


if( $_SESSION['IDLinha'] ) {
    $querydatahora .= $conn->prepare(" AND Avarias.IDLinha = :IDLinha AND Avarias.IDMaquina = :IDMaquina order by DataHoraInicioAvaria DESC LIMIT $startrow, 9");
} else{
    $querydatahora .= $conn->prepare(" order by DataHoraInicioAvaria DESC LIMIT $startrow, 9");
}

$querydatahora->execute( array(
    ':datetimepicker'   => $_SESSION['datetimepicker'], 
    ':datetimepicker1'  => $_SESSION['datetimepicker1'], 
    ':IDLinha'          => $_SESSION['IDLinha'], 
    ':IDMaquina'        => $_SESSION['IDMaquina'])
);

if( $_SESSION['IDLinha'] ) {
    $querycount .= $conn->prepare(' AND Avarias.IDLinha = :IDLinha AND Avarias.IDMaquina = :IDMaquina');
}

$querycount->execute( array(
    ':datetimepicker'   => $_SESSION['datetimepicker'], 
    ':datetimepicker1'  => $_SESSION['datetimepicker1'], 
    ':IDLinha'          => $_SESSION['IDLinha'], 
    ':IDMaquina'        => $_SESSION['IDMaquina'])
);
```

The error i'm getting is:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php on line 52

I'm not an expert on this so, probably i'm making something wrong. All the help is appreciated

Comment: `prepare()` returns a `PDOStatement` object which is where your exception is coming from, it's not a string. You should only pass `prepare()` the full query, i.e. generate the SQL query (with placeholders) into a string, then run `prepare()` passing the completed query string.

Comment: You need to assemble your query before calling $conn->prepare...
$querydatahora isn't a string like "SELECT..." as you might think but an object htat received a prepared statement based on that string.

Comment: I think would be easier if you use join ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build a query string first.

```
$querydatahora = 'SELECT Linhas.NomeLinha, Maquinas.Nome as maquina, Tecnicos.Nome, Avarias.DataHoraInicioAvaria, Avarias.DataHoraFimAvaria, Avarias.Descricao, Avarias.Solucao, Avarias.TipoSolucao 
FROM Avarias, Tecnicos, Linhas, Maquinas, avariatecnico where Linhas.IDLinha = Avarias.IDLinha and avariatecnico.IDAvaria = avarias.IDAvaria and Avariatecnico.IDTecnico = Tecnicos.IDTecnico and 
Maquinas.IDMaquina = Avarias.IDMaquina and DataHoraInicioAvaria >= :datetimepicker AND DataHoraFimAvaria <= :datetimepicker1'

// Your minimal parameters
$params = array(':datetimepicker' => $_SESSION['datetimepicker'], ':datetimepicker1' => $_SESSION['datetimepicker1']);

// Test you have the mandatory variables IDLinha and IDMaquina
if (isset($_SESSION['IDLinha']) && isset($_SESSION['IDMaquina'])) {
    $querydatahora .= " AND Avarias.IDLinha = :IDLinha AND Avarias.IDMaquina = :IDMaquina");
    // Adding parameters
    $params = array_merge($params, array(':IDLinha' => $_SESSION['IDLinha'],':IDMaquina' => $_SESSION['IDMaquina']));
}

// In anyway you will do the same order by then write it at the end
$querydatahora .= " order by DataHoraInicioAvaria DESC LIMIT $startrow, 9";

// Your querystring is ok then let's prepare it
$stmt = $conn->prepare($querydatahora);

// Now Run with parameters
$stmt->execute($params);
```

I have removed your querycount because I want to focus on the first query and make it work

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on string in line "$querydatahora->execute($params);"

Comment: Updated: replace $querydatahora->execute with $conn->execute

Comment: `$stmt = $conn->prepare(...); $stmt->execute(...)` you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Now i'm having problems with the fetchcolumn() because i have $total = $querydatahora->fetchColumn();
But i'll try to fix it.

Comment: $querydatahora is a string, you can use fetchColumn on the statement : $stmt->fetchColumn()

Comment: My variables datetimepicker and datetimepicker1 need to be with ' ' in the statement, where do i put them? on the $sql or in the $params!?

Comment: use $conn->quote($_SESSION['datetimepicker'])

Comment: Something is not working well because i have records on the database but the application gives the message "no records found" that i send when the fetchColumn() is equal to 0. Anything that we could've missed?

Comment: Your query may return 0 row because the matching with criterias.

The problem is probably in your query itself. Print it (echo $querydatahora), replace the placeholder with your values and run it on your sql client.

Comment: The problem is that IDLinha and IDMaquina are optional (most the time are not filled) and they are being passed to the statement as blank fields. And the select returns nothing. They would only be added to the statement if they are filled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91112/discussion-between-bang-and-vallete7).

Answer (score 3):

You need first build the query and after that prepare it

```
$sql = 'SELECT Linhas.NomeLinha,
               Maquinas.Nome as maquina,
               Tecnicos.Nome, 
               Avarias.DataHoraInicioAvaria,
               Avarias.DataHoraFimAvaria,
               Avarias.Descricao,
               Avarias.Solucao, 
               Avarias.TipoSolucao 
        FROM Avarias, Tecnicos, Linhas, Maquinas, avariatecnico
        WHERE Linhas.IDLinha = Avarias.IDLinha
        AND avariatecnico.IDAvaria = avarias.IDAvaria
        AND Avariatecnico.IDTecnico = Tecnicos.IDTecnico
        AND Maquinas.IDMaquina = Avarias.IDMaquina
        AND DataHoraInicioAvaria >= :datetimepicker
        AND DataHoraFimAvaria <= :datetimepicker1 ';

if ($_SESSION['IDLinha']) {
    $querydatahora = $conn->prepare($sql." AND Avarias.IDLinha = :IDLinha
                                           AND Avarias.IDMaquina = :IDMaquina
                                           ORDER BY DataHoraInicioAvaria
                                           DESC LIMIT $startrow, 9");
}else{
    $querydatahora = $conn->prepare($sql." ORDER BY DataHoraInicioAvaria
                                           DESC LIMIT $startrow, 9");
}


$params = array(':datetimepicker' => $_SESSION['datetimepicker'],
                ':datetimepicker1' => $_SESSION['datetimepicker1'],
                ':IDLinha' => $_SESSION['IDLinha'],
                ':IDMaquina' => $_SESSION['IDMaquina']
                );

$querydatahora->execute($params);

$params = array(':datetimepicker' => $_SESSION['datetimepicker'],
               ':datetimepicker1' => $_SESSION['datetimepicker1']);

if ($_SESSION['IDLinha']) {
    $querycount = $conn->prepare($sql.' AND Avarias.IDLinha = :IDLinha 
                                        AND Avarias.IDMaquina = :IDMaquina');
    $params[':IDLinha'] = $_SESSION['IDLinha'];
    $params[':IDMaquina']  $_SESSION['IDMaquina'];
}

$querycount->execute($params);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried that example but i got the following errors:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxx.php on line 61

Notice: Undefined variable: querycount in C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php on line 67

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on null in C:xxxxxxxxxxxxx.php on line 67